# Add pause/play functionality on carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I add functionality of play and pause on this carousel please help me..
  code is here below link:

http://jsfiddle.net/P5295/

```
<div id="carousel">
    <figure>1</figure>
    <figure>2</figure>
    <figure>3</figure>
    <figure>4</figure>
    <figure>5</figure>
    <figure>6</figure>
    <figure>7</figure>
    <figure>8</figure>
    <figure>9</figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Why downvote this question. Its a totally valid question with demo provided.

Answer (score 1):

Add following CSS to pause on hover. [Here is the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/P5295/4/).

```
#carousel:hover {
    -webkit-animation-play-state : paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state : paused;
    -o-animation-play-state : paused;
    animation-play-state : paused;
}
```

[Try this example](http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/P5295/5/) if you want to pause using a button. In this case the only problem is that button has to be next to the Carousel.

If you want your button to be anywhere else not next to carousel, than you have to use JS/jQuery [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/P5295/6/).

If you want to pause and resume using button click, [try this example](http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/P5295/7/)

If you want 2 buttons for stop and start, [try this one](http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/P5295/8/)

Comment: great its working on hover but what if i want same functionality by using button when i click on button it paused

Comment: i want when i click on this button then it paused  please help me

Comment: i want that when i click on button then it paused

Comment: Check the updated answer as I said. Check the last link in answer http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/P5295/7/

Comment: if i wnt 2 button one for play and one for pause  then what i have to do

Comment: I wish you mentioned these things clearly in your question :/  check this http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/P5295/8/

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, please select it

Answer (score 0):

If You want do this by pure CSS only way is the add :hover effect

```
    #carousel:hover {
    -webkit-animation-play-state : paused !important;
}
```

If you want to use jquery the easiest way is toglling predefined class.

```
$( "#button" ).click(function() {
  $('#carousel').toggleClass( "carouselStop" );
});
```

The next way is css toogling but in my example toogle efect work this way only for 1.83 jquery and older(in newest version we can write function with if)

```
$("#button2").toggle(
function(){$("#carousel").css({'-webkit-animation-play-state': 'paused'});},
function(){$("#carousel").css({'-webkit-animation-play-state': ''});}
);
```

Here is the Examples of these three methods: http://jsfiddle.net/gyycV/1/

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="carouselButtons">
<button id="playButton" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
 </button>
<button id="pauseButton" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause"></span>
</button>
```

Then the following JavaScript should control starting and stopping on any frame:

```
$('#playButton').click(function () {
$('#homeCarousel').carousel('cycle');
});
$('#pauseButton').click(function () {

$('#homeCarousel').carousel('pause');
});
```

Check this link http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/XFcSv/